# (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging) Injection EventSource in SqlDatabaseLog.EnableEvents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

I have just recently added Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging (v6) with SqlServer silk in my MVC 4 application.

```
var sqlListener = SqlDatabaseLog.CreateListener("SampleEventLogger",strConnection);
sqlListener.EnableEvents(BasicLogger.Log, EventLevel.LogAlways);
```

this is the code in my controller

```
BasicLogger.Log.Critical("ERROR CRITICAL");
```

It works well!

...and now the impediment :) 
In my MVC application I use Unity for DI and I inject into constructor ILogger interface.
Because I need to use the same reference that I have registered into unity container (otherwise doesn't work) ,so I have thought that taking the RegisteredType could be the solution.

```
 var myRegistereType = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
 sqlListener.EnableEvents(myRegistereType, EventLevel.LogAlways);
```

but I received an error

**There is already an instance of EventSource with Guid XXX XXX XXX XXX **

Does anyone have any idea? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one instance of an EventSource.  This is why you will usually see an EventSource exposing a singleton instance (e.g. `BasicLogger.Log`).

If you are using Unity you will have to register the EventSource as a singleton or use another approach that results in one instance being returned.  Here is one way to do it using an InjectionFactory and the Log property:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<ILogger>(
    new InjectionFactory(c => BasicLogger.Log));

var logger = container.Resolve<ILogger>();
```